# LinkButton CommandName not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, linkbutton

I have a link button ( the text of the link button is edit )   in a gridview , i give it a commandname call modify

So in my design the code is :

```
   <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="modify">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
           </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

And in my code behind is :

```
  protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton linkBtn = (LinkButton)sender;

    if (linkBtn.CommandName == "modify") // tried linkBtn.CommandArguemtn , doesn't help
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);       

        Label login = (Label)GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].FindControl("Label1");
       //Things i want to do 

    }
}
```

As you can see i set the panel to be visible , but it won't appear ... am i doing the correct way? i know of an alternative which is to use the default edit button generated , but i don't want to do that . I am trying to put a link button in a gridview and click on the link button and then panel ( consists of textboxs controls ) should appear then make changes of the gridview data in the panel .

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "modify")
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);       

        Label login = (Label)GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].FindControl("Label1");
       //Things i want to do 

    }
}
```

you wont need to check the button first, `e.CommandName` will be sufficent

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.use the `CommandName` property to specify or determine the command name [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName=="modify")
        {
            \\
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{


    if (e.CommandName.ToLower()== "modify") 
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);       

        Label login = (Label)GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].FindControl("Label1");
       //Things i want to do 

    }
}
```